# matplotlib xaxis.set_major_formatter extra dates

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

thanks to a LOT of help from overflowers I have FINALLY got formatted dates on my plot HOORAY!! BUT now there are too many of them! Can anyone see why please? I have only included the relevant list being plotted not the code.
here is the x_list

```
x_list [datetime.date(2015, 8, 4), datetime.date(2015, 8, 5), datetime.date(2015, 8, 6), datetime.date(2015, 8, 7)]
```

here's the format

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
```

here's the plot

[image: extra dates]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer if you had included your code but I think this should fix it. You just need to specify what ticks should be included, using `set_ticks()`:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime    

x_list = [datetime.date(2015, 8, 4), datetime.date(2015, 8, 5), datetime.date(2015, 8, 6), datetime.date(2015, 8, 7)]
y = [5, 7, 3, 9] # just an example

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m-%d'))
ax.plot(x_list, y)
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(x_list)

plt.show()
```

Comment: perfect thanks so much. I still don't see why it happened but your solution was exactly right. thank you for showing me a new aspect of matplotlib

Comment: you're welcome :-) By default, matplotlib will automatically set the number of ticks. If you need a specific number of ticks, you should specify it.

Comment: There is also a set of date-related locators http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers which may be useful here.

Comment: thanks again you are a star :-) all this is really helpful to a noob.